# Interval in a Greasemonkey script is not waiting

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am using Greasemonkey to click a button on a page every 100 seconds. So far, I am able to get the JS to click the button but it's not waiting the 100 seconds.

I am not getting any error, but the `setInterval` just is not waiting before moving on.  Thanks!

The code:

```
console.log('script start');
var int =self.setInterval(function(){clickConfirmButton(e)},100000);
console.log('script start waiting');
function clickConfirmButton(e) {
 var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
 var clicked = false;
 for (var index=0; index < buttons.length; index++){
  if(buttons[index].textContent == "check"){
   buttons[index].click();
   clicked = true;
   break;
  }
 }
 if(!clicked){
  setTimeout("window.location.reload()",300*1000);
 }
}
clickConfirmButton();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this function call at the end:

```
clickConfirmButton();
```

It completely bypasses the 100-second timer.  Delete or comment-out that line.